# Rails 4 ActionMailer Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

I have created a rails app for booking cabs online. I want my app to have the functionality of sending emails to users once their booking is confirmed. For this, I am following Ryan Bates railscasts:

`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v1KI571TdUQ`

I started with creating a setup_mail.rb file in app/config/initializers, with the following content:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port                 => 587,
  :domain               => "railscasts.com",
  :user_name            => "taxibol",
  :password             => "secret",
  :authentication       => "plain",
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

I then generated a mailer named user_mailer and included the following in app/mailers/user_mailer.rb:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
    default :from => "no-reply@taxibol.in"
  def registration_confirmation(user)
    mail(:to => user.email, :subject => "Registered")
  end
end
```

and the following in app/views/user_mailer/registration_confirmation.text.erb:

```
Welcome to example.com!
===============================================

You have successfully signed up to taxibol.in.

Thanks for joining and have a great day!
```

Finally, in my static_pages_controller.rb, I included the following:

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
    def booking_confirmation
        UserMailer.registration_confirmation(current_user).deliver
    end
end
```

I tested this in my localhost env, and it seems to have worked. Following is the relevant section in

```
Started GET "/booking/confirmation" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-12-13 08:30:14 -0800
Processing by StaticPagesController#booking_confirmation as HTML
  ←[1m←[35mUser Load (2.5ms)←[0m  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Rendered user_mailer/registration_confirmation.text.erb (0.0ms)

UserMailer#registration_confirmation: processed outbound mail in 10.0ms

Sent mail to rahul.pod@gmail.com (2037.5ms)
Date: Sat, 13 Dec 2014 08:30:14 -0800
From: no-reply@taxibol.in
To: rahul.pod@gmail.com
Message-ID: <548c6996cb448_32b42adff3848954@Rolu.mail>
Subject: Registered
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Welcome to example.com!
===============================================

You have successfully signed up to taxibol.in.

Thanks for joining and have a great day!
```

However, I checked my gmail account (rahul.pod@gmail.com), but I didn't receive any mail. What could be the reason?

**Update:**

Instead of creating the setup_mail.rb file, I tried to include the following in config/environments/development.rb:

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {host: 'localhost', port: 3000}

  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: "smtp.gmail.com",
    port: "587",
    domain: "gmail.com"
    authentication: "plain",
    enable_starttls_auto: true,
    user_name: "no_reply@taxibol.in"
    password: "some_password"
  }
```

Again got the same log trails, but no mail yet :(

Comment: try a `gmail` id in `user_name`

Comment: Tried that as well Nitin...but no result :( BTW...what should go into domain? Any idea?

Comment: domain is right, change default :from address and give a try..

Comment: I'd try that with `mailcatcher` first.

Comment: D-side: I tried with mailcatcher and it works. So the problem seems to be in the SMTP settings. Can someone point where am I going wrong in the SMTP settings? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @SwetaLal everything looks right. did you check your spam box once.

Comment: Yes I did Nitin... :(

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you tried keeping :user_name with full domain extension. So it should be something like this:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
 :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
 :port                 => 587,
 :domain               => "railscasts.com",
 :user_name            => "contactus@taxobol.in",
 :password             => "secret",
 :authentication       => "plain",
 :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

Also Google Apps has per day 100 email limit. Check if you have already exhausted that limit which might be causing this.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try [this gist](https://gist.github.com/Nosfheratu/385995329a93510e380b) and set your own credential for gmail?